# Firefox quantum browser cursor bugs

Tags: firefox, mozilla, firefox-quantum

Cursor appears in strange places
[Near inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yujR.png)

[In the preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2Ogq.png)

Comment: What do you expect us to do? You should file a bug report to Mozilla.

Comment: Actually, you are right.. I just didn't find a fast way to do what you recommended.. So, I supposed that maybe some firefox devs read this here. Just a hope, lol.